# Visual C++ .net vs C++

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

Kindly can any one point to the main differences between C++ and Visual C++ .net?
Is Visual C++ .net a managed code like C# and VB? Does it use the same FCL and BCL? Can C# and VB dlls be consumed from a visual C++ .Net project?

Answer (score 6):

C++ is a language; Visual C++ is a compiler for the C, C++, and C++/CLI languages.

What you *probably* mean to ask about is the difference between C++ and C++/CLI, but a quick SO search will demonstrate that question to already be answered many times over.

> Is Visual C++ .net a managed code like C# and VB?

C++/CLI is, yes.

> Does it use the same FCL and BCL?

Yes.

> Can C# and VB dlls be consumed from a visual C++ .Net project?

From a C++/CLI project, yes; and the reverse is also true.

Comment: "C++/CLI is, yes." <-- This is slightly oversimplified. C++/CLI does generate native code, unless compiled with `/clr:safe`, which disallows all native constructs (i.e. everything needs to be made a `ref class`). C++/CLI embeds both managed and unmanaged code in a single binary. (This is why you can't just take off the shelf C++ code, compile as C++/CLI, and run it in low trust areas like Silverlight or the Phone)

Comment: @Billy ONeal : No, it doesn't generate native code unless `#pragma unmanaged` is used; otherwise, native classes and functions are compiled into unverifiable MSIL.

Comment: Oops.. you are correct. I'm still thinking in "Managed C++" land. :( However, the point about it being unusable in contexts where you do not have full trust still stands.

Comment: @Billy ONeal : Sure, but that's hardly language specific. The same stands for using `fixed` or `unsafe` in C#, using reflection to access private members from any language, etc.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, in the other languages it's made obvious where you've made the security violation; while in C++/CLI it's implicit. And making the C++/CLI "safe" is usually a large enough change that it should probably be rewritten in C# if you need to target the CLR that much.

Answer (score 0):

C++ is a language.

Microsoft Visual C++ is a development environment for the C++ language. It includes a compiler, editor, debugger and much more.